# How do I create a 'rate this app' button in an Air app for iOS

Tags: ios, flash, actionscript-3, air

I often see a 'rate this app'-button in ios apps and want to recreate it in my own apps for ios. As i am working in Adobe AIR i can't use any of the native libraries linked in the answer below.

My question is - how do i make a 'rate this app'-button in an iOS app created with Adobe AIR?
I can't find any Air Native Extensions (ANE) covering this specific case so i am thinking maybe there is a simpler way - maybe i just need a special link from the app to the app-store?

Comment: Did you ever find the answer to this?

Comment: Nope! Sure would like one though - but apparently not here :-)

Answer (score 2):

There is a really nice project called [iRate](https://github.com/nicklockwood/iRate) by Nick Lockwood, just mind project's license.

Comment: +1 for neat project link - at the first glance, the documentation looks really well done. Kudos to the author - will keep an eye on that project for sure.

Comment: At first glance it looks like just what i need, only as i am developing in adobe air - it needs to be actionscript or native extension.